# How to download video format 1 or format 2 using youtube-dl?

Tags: youtube-dl

I have a video play-list with type "22" and type "18" videos, only when there is no type "22" video I would go for type 18 one.

Can I know a way that I can download type 22 or type 18 videos based on the best quality video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"22" is always better, its resolutions is 1280x720 and for "18" it is 640x360. So:

```
 youtube-dl  -f '22/18'  [link]/[playlist]
```

It will going to download "22" if it was available, if not it's going for "18" and if neither were available it will complain that no suitable formats are available for download.

Have a look at `man youtube-dl`, "format selection" section.